# Come out of while loop in shell scripting

Tags: bash, shell, while-loop, break

I have the following code

```
echo "Please Enter the Email Id"
while read -r email
do
if
    echo "$email" | grep -v   "awt"
    then
    echo "You entered a invalid email id please try again"
    break
    fi
    echo "================You chose Email id as $email"
done

echo "Please Enter the user Name"
read -r name
    echo "you entered $name"
echo Final email id $email
echo final name     $name
```

When iam trying  to execute the above code, Iam not able to come enter the second condition, that is it does not come out of the loop.
What I need is it should ask until the user  enters the correct email id and after that it should go to the next set of codes and finally print the final echo statement

Comment: Insert before `break` a line with `else`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
while :; do
   read -rp 'Please Enter the Email Id: ' email
   if [[ $email != *awt* ]]; then
      echo "You entered an invalid email id please try again"
   else
      break
   fi
done
```

Comment: This is perfect Thankyou soo much . I would love to get a small explanation on " while :; " Thanks a lot once again

Comment: `while :` is actually make it an infinite loop

Comment: If i want to print that you have entered correct email id , How am i supposed to do that?

Comment: Got it, I was writing it after the break statement